# How to send a comment (in 1 table) to all users (referring to another table)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Right now I have 2 tables. A comment table and a user table. Short and simple, I wanna sent a comment to all users. I need to know the sql command for it and how to display on PHP.

Comment table

> 1. pk
> 2. comment
> 3. sender (refers to username)
> 4. receiver (refers to username)

User table

> 1. pk
> 2. username
> 3. etc.....

I tried using this:

```
$provider = $_REQUEST['provider'];

$cert = $_REQUEST['cert'];

$valid = $_REQUEST['valid'];

$lprice = $_REQUEST['lprice'];

$trial = $_REQUEST['trial'];

$cost = $_REQUEST['cost'];

echo $cert;

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sslcert WHERE CertificateName='$cert'",$connect);
 if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0)
   {
    echo"SSL already exists.";
    echo "<br><a href=addssl.php>Back</a>";
   }
 else
    {
      $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sslcert (Provider, CertificateName, Validation,                    
      ListPrice, Trial, Cost) VALUES ('$provider', '$cert', '$valid', '$lprice', 
     '$trial',     '$cost')",$connect);


          $result77=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user");
     while($row77=mysql_fetch_array($result77))
     {
       $insert1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO notification (msg, sender, receiver,   notification) VALUES ('A new product is now available, $cert by $provider', '$username',   '$row77['username']', 1)");
       if(!$insert1){

            die("There's little problem: ".mysql_error());
            echo "<br><a href=quotesmanage1.php>Back</a>";
        }
     }

    if(!$insert){

       die("There's little problem: ".mysql_error());
       echo "<br><a href=addssl.php>Back</a>";
    }

    echo "<br>You have add a new Product <br><a href=adminhome.php>Back to Home</a>";

    }   
    mysql_close($connect);
}
```

the call for username is somewhere else on the page.
It came out with a blank page (error on php), any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting please?

Comment: Not gonna talk about injections in your code and the use of Mysqli or pdo, but from what I understand is that for each time you run a the result of a query, you want to insert a value that is not parsed right :) cause $cert and $provider arent now values. Make them ` ... now available, ".$cert." by ".$provider."', ...`

Comment: Blank page with no error, desu ka? You should probably echo your `INSERT` query before executing it.

Comment: Just edited, yes a plain white page appeared, showing absolutely nothing

Comment: echo $cert; also not showing anything?

Comment: If I remove the insert command for the comments, it completely works...

Comment: which insert command - 'INSERT INTO sslcert' or 'INSERT INTO notification' ?

Comment: notification, pls ignore the other insert...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want a INSERT...SELECT query.

```
INSERT INTO `Comment`(`Comment`.`comment`, `Comment`.`sender`, `Comment`.`receiver`)
SELECT 'Message as text or variable substitution', `User`.`pk`, '1'
FROM `User`
```

You can substitute any ID instead of 1 at the end of the SELECT line, I just figured your administrative user is probably 1 (but you can create a new user for sending these mass messages and just use whatever number ID corresponds.

By the way, in your comment table you should probably reference User.pk, not User.username. That's sort of why you have the key in the first place :-)